# Throughput tool with decent graphing

Tags: bandwidth, rrdtool, iperf

I've been looking through some of the tools available for generating traffic to measure maximum network throughput, namely iperf, bwping, ttcp, etc. I am planning on doing throughput tests over a long period of time, so what I really need is good graphing output, preferably rrd graphs.

The Jperf frontend for iperf will generate a graph, and bmon has a nice command-line graph, but these simply count seconds since the test was started. I am trying to measure trends in throughput over times of the day, so a graph with times and days is necessary.

So a way to get iperf to log to RRDs would be best, if this isn't possible could someone point me toward another solution?

EDIT: I have had ntop suggested, which does produce the types of graphs I like, but ntop lacks the ability to generate traffic, it just monitors. I guess I could run ntop while running iperf tests, but again, if anyone has an "all-in-one" solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ntop is what I would use for what you describe.  NMIS could also help too for switch or other network device monitoring.

- [Ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)
- [NMIS](http://www.sins.com.au/nmis/)

Comment: I had been looking at ntop and it is great for monitoring current traffic, with graphs. What I am actually looking for (i will clarify my question) is something like iperf that actually generates its own traffic. I am trying to see the max possible throughput on this link.

Comment: I was going to suggest running ntop with something that generates the traffic.  Otherwise, create your own rrd graphs and run it all via a script, if you really want to just run a single command.

Good luck.

Comment: Many thanks for input. I'm going to ahead with using ntop for monitoring and iperf for generating traffic.